# Positive integers $n$ so that $n^2$ divides $2^n+1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $n$ for which $n^2$ divides $2^n+1$.

Comment: The solution can be found here http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/SatoNT.pdf on page 33. But id try to prove it before you look at the solution.